# Nginx getting file not found on dynamic root

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I am trying to load two different react app one on root level and one on sub location i.e /in. What I am doing is I am checking if $uri consist `/in /t` if that condition is true it will change root path after setting root path I am serving index file. Its not working its throwing `404 not found` when i am trying to access `domain.com/in/something` and `domain.com` is working fine.

I don't know is it right way to do this or not. I tried this

Here is my nginx config file:

```
server {

   server_name domain.com;
   rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
   set $rootpath "/var/www/html/website/public";

   location / {
        if ($uri ~ \/(in|t)\/){
            add_header X-uri "$uri";
            set $rootpath "/var/www/html/app/build";
        }

        root $rootpath;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
   }
}
```